# Is there a way to post a File and FormGroup to my API?

Tags: angular, api, .net-core

i'm actually working on an Angular 6 application with .NET Core and in this application I have a UserForm where the user enter his informations and also a picture.

**The form submit without the picture is working well, and the picture submit without the form also.**
But now i want to make a global submit, but i got a 400 ERROR:

**"Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated"**

I think the problem is my service post method...

Here is my userService post method:

```
postUser(userFormAdd: FormGroup,file): Observable<Boolean> {
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", file);
    let data = {          
        user: userFormAdd.value,
        fileData: input,
    };
    return this.http.post<Boolean>(AppSettings.URL + "/users/", data); 
}
```

I combined the user model and the file in a UserViewModel:

```
public class UserCreationViewModel
 {
     public User user { get; set; }
     public IFormFile fileData { get; set; }
 }
```

My controller post method is not even called:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostUser([FromBody]UserCreationViewModel userViewModel)
        {

          var test = await _siteService.CreateUser(userViewModel);

                return Ok();
        }
```

I expect to retrieve my picture by a IFormFile and my Form value in my controller method but actually i only have a 400 ERROR

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to send each property of your User next to the file rather than sending the User Object ? Post => Username, Password, FIle rather than Post => User, FileData ?

Answer (score 0):

try the below one:

```
 let input = new FormData();
        input.append("file", file);
        input.append("user", userFormAdd.value);
        return this.http.post<Boolean>(AppSettings.URL + "/users/", input);
```

If still issue persists split your UserFormAdd items and append in FormData()

Comment: still 400 error, but the error has changed in "the input was not valid". I dont think that i can split items because UserFormAdd is a nested from group :/

Comment: you need to analyse the backend in which format it is accepting input. You can also use some tool like Postman to check. And 400 you will get until your request format is not matching with backend.

Answer (score 0):

I got something new, I used [FromForm] and i'm getting into my Controller method with the FileData but User FormGroup is still empty.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostUser([FromForm]UserCreationViewModel userViewModel)
        {

          var test = await _siteService.CreateUser(userViewModel);

                return Ok();
        }
```

My service

```
postUser(userFormAdd: FormGroup,file) {
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", file);
    input.append("user",userFormAdd.value);
    return this.http.post<Boolean>(AppSettings.URL + "/users/", data).subscribe(); 
}
```

I tried to stringify my FormGroup value with no success.

EDIT - SOLUTION :

I passed each field of my FormGroup in "input" so we have a thing like this :

```
postUser(userFormAdd: FormGroup,file) {
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", file);
    input.append("name",userFormAdd.value.name);
    input.append("city",userFormAdd.value.city);
    input.append("address",userFormAdd.value.address);
    return this.http.post<Boolean>(AppSettings.URL + "/users/", data).subscribe(); 
}
```

Dont forget to update your controller viewModel with every field that you added